# Using BackStretch.js to automatically stretch existing background images?

Tags: jquery, css, performance, background-image

I've got some background images already on a page (a lot of them... I'd rather avoid recoding a bunch) and I need to fill them cross browser (stretch). [BackStretch.js](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) can do this but it seems like it needs to be manually done. I can't use background-size because it dosen't work on IE8 (there's polyfills) but most importantly it lags out in webkit due to not caching anything. Ideas?

Comment: Would you be able to post a sample of your classes and their background image styles?

Comment: div.ENS
{
    background-size: cover;
      background-image: url("content/pieces/ENS.png");
}

div.ESW
{
    background-size: cover;
      background-image: url("content/pieces/ESW.png");
}

div.ENSW
{
    background-size: cover;
      background-image: url("content/pieces/ENSW.png");
}

There's a lot of those for a lot of different permutations and suffixes. Probably about 50 of them total.

Comment: Thanks for posting them, how are they removed and added? Is it some kind of slideshow?

Comment: No, it's just through jQuery addclass. They're added and removing through various means - and not really wrapped. A potential candidate solution I thought of was to hook an event for the classes changing and extracting their background image properties.

Answer (score 0):

Backstretch.js is manual. All you would have to do is remove the background images from your css (save the paths and selectors to a scratch file or something) and then fire off backstretch using those same paths. Shouldn't be too much of an overhaul.

Comment: They're on a bunch of classes that are constantly removed and added... ugh that's going to be painful.

Comment: If those classes are added via JS you could fire off Backstretch at that point?

Comment: Potentially - if I can extract the existing path from the CSS and over-ride it via Backstretch.js Something I was hoping to be able to do. I'm just not sure *HOW.